# Vertex skinning - need help figuring out what's wrong

Tags: c++, animation, vertex-shader

I'm currently working on a gameengine. It's built upon WGPU and c++. I'm trying to read a GLTF file and animate a human character.

I've verified that the matrices are sent to the shader correctly since the mesh is actually transformed. See image below.

[image: Exploded mesh]

As you can see the transform is all messed up. I think it's because the bones being updated incorrectly and the matrices are calculated wrong.

Code:

First i Read the boneIds and weights:

```
            // Assuming each vertex has 4 bone IDs and 4 bone weights (common in glTF)
            int numVertices = jointsAccessor.count;

            for (int vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < numVertices; ++vertexIndex)
            {
                int ids[4] = {-1, -1, -1, -1};           // Initialize bone IDs to -1 (indicating invalid bone)
                float weights[4] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}; // Initialize bone weights to 0.0

                // Loop through the actual number of bone weights for this vertex
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
                {
                    ids[i] = static_cast<uint16_t>(boneIds[vertexIndex * 4 + i]);
                    weights[i] = boneWeights[vertexIndex * 4 + i];
                }

                mesh->_vertexData[vertexIndex].boneId = glm::vec4(ids[0], ids[1], ids[2], ids[3]);
                mesh->_vertexData[vertexIndex].weights = glm::vec4(weights[0], weights[1], weights[2], weights[3]);
            }
```

then i traverse the bone hierarchy:

```
// Recursive function to traverse the bone hierarchy and apply vertex skinning
void TraverseBoneHierarchy(const tinygltf::Model &model, const tinygltf::Node &node)
{
    Bone bone;
    bone.name = node.name;
    bone.m_LocalTransform = glm::mat4(1.0);

    // Duration of animation
    double maxDuration = 0.0;

    for (size_t animIndex = 0; animIndex < model.animations.size(); animIndex++)
    {
        const tinygltf::Animation &animation = model.animations[animIndex];

        // Process samplers (access keyframe data)
        const tinygltf::AnimationSampler &sampler = animation.samplers[0];

        // Extract position keyframes.
        for (const auto &channel : animation.channels)
        {
            if (channel.target_path == "translation")
            {
                const tinygltf::Accessor &accessor = model.accessors[sampler.input];
                const tinygltf::BufferView &bufferView = model.bufferViews[accessor.bufferView];
                const tinygltf::Buffer &buffer = model.buffers[bufferView.buffer];
                const float *keyframeTimesData = reinterpret_cast<const float *>(&buffer.data[bufferView.byteOffset + accessor.byteOffset]);
                int keyframeCount = accessor.count;

                const tinygltf::Accessor &outputAccessor = model.accessors[sampler.output];
                const tinygltf::BufferView &outputBufferView = model.bufferViews[outputAccessor.bufferView];
                const tinygltf::Buffer &outputBuffer = model.buffers[outputBufferView.buffer];
                const float *positionData = reinterpret_cast<const float *>(&outputBuffer.data[outputBufferView.byteOffset + outputAccessor.byteOffset]);

                for (int i = 0; i < keyframeCount; ++i)
                {
                    KeyPosition keyPosition;
                    keyPosition.position = glm::vec3(positionData[i * 3], positionData[i * 3 + 1], positionData[i * 3 + 2]);
                    keyPosition.timeStamp = static_cast<float>(keyframeTimesData[i]);
                    bone.m_Positions.push_back(keyPosition);
                }
            }
        }

        // Extract rotation keyframes.
        for (const auto &channel : animation.channels)
        {
            if (channel.target_path == "rotation")
            {

                const tinygltf::Accessor &accessor = model.accessors[sampler.input];
                const tinygltf::BufferView &bufferView = model.bufferViews[accessor.bufferView];
                const tinygltf::Buffer &buffer = model.buffers[bufferView.buffer];
                const float *keyframeTimesData = reinterpret_cast<const float *>(&buffer.data[bufferView.byteOffset + accessor.byteOffset]);
                int keyframeCount = accessor.count;

                const tinygltf::Accessor &outputAccessor = model.accessors[sampler.output];
                const tinygltf::BufferView &outputBufferView = model.bufferViews[outputAccessor.bufferView];
                const tinygltf::Buffer &outputBuffer = model.buffers[outputBufferView.buffer];
                const float *rotationData = reinterpret_cast<const float *>(&outputBuffer.data[outputBufferView.byteOffset + outputAccessor.byteOffset]);

                for (int i = 0; i < keyframeCount; ++i)
                {
                    KeyRotation keyRotation;
                    keyRotation.orientation = glm::quat(rotationData[i * 4], rotationData[i * 4 + 1], rotationData[i * 4 + 2], rotationData[i * 4 + 3]);
                    keyRotation.timeStamp = static_cast<float>(keyframeTimesData[i]);
                    bone.m_Rotations.push_back(keyRotation);
                }
            }
        }

        // Access the input time data (keyframe times)
        const tinygltf::Accessor &timeAccessor = model.accessors[sampler.input];
        const tinygltf::BufferView &timeBufferView = model.bufferViews[timeAccessor.bufferView];
        const tinygltf::Buffer &timeBuffer = model.buffers[timeBufferView.buffer];
        const float *times = reinterpret_cast<const float *>(&timeBuffer.data[timeAccessor.byteOffset + timeBufferView.byteOffset]);

        double duration = timeAccessor.maxValues[0];

        if (duration > maxDuration)
        {
            maxDuration = duration;
        }
    }

    // Add the bone to the vector
    m_Bones.push_back(bone);

    int boneID = -1;
    std::string boneName = node.name;
    if (m_BoneInfoMap.find(boneName) == m_BoneInfoMap.end())
    {
        BoneInfo newBoneInfo;
        newBoneInfo.id = m_BoneCounter;
        newBoneInfo.offset = ComputeBoneMatrix(node);
        m_BoneInfoMap[boneName] = newBoneInfo;
        boneID = m_BoneCounter;
        m_BoneCounter++;
    }
    else
    {
        boneID = m_BoneInfoMap[boneName].id;
    }

    // Recursive call for each child bone
    for (int childIndex : node.children)
    {
        TraverseBoneHierarchy(model, model.nodes[childIndex]);
    }

    m_Duration = maxDuration;
}
```

and the calculate the bone transforms:

```
void CalculateBoneTransform(const tinygltf::Node *node, glm::mat4 parentTransform)
{
    std::string nodeName = node->name;
    glm::mat4 nodeTransform = glm::mat4(1.0);

    Bone *Bone = m_CurrentAnimation->FindBone(nodeName);

    if (Bone)
    {
        Bone->Update(m_CurrentTime);
        nodeTransform = Bone->m_LocalTransform;
    }

    glm::mat4 globalTransformation = parentTransform * nodeTransform;

    auto boneInfoMap = m_CurrentAnimation->GetBoneIDMap();

    if (boneInfoMap.find(nodeName) != boneInfoMap.end())
    {
        int index = boneInfoMap[nodeName].id;
        glm::mat4 offset = boneInfoMap[nodeName].offset;
        m_FinalBoneMatrices[index] = globalTransformation * offset;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < node->children.size(); i++)
    {
        CalculateBoneTransform(&m_CurrentAnimation->model.model.nodes[node->children[i]], globalTransformation);
    }
}
```

The vertex shader (WGSL):

```
  var totalPosition = vec4<f32>(pos, 1.0);
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
      var localPosition = uModel.finalBonesMatrices[u32(in.boneId[i])] * vec4(pos, 1.0);
      totalPosition += localPosition * in.weights[i];
  }

  var viewModel = uMyUniforms.viewMatrix * uModel.modelMatrix;
  out.position = uMyUniforms.projectionMatrix * viewModel * totalPosition;
```

I can't really figure out what's wrong. I've messed around with the code for some time now but it always seem to end up in this exploded figure in attached image.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Probably nobody is going to be able to debug this from code alone. I suggest you take a step back and create a much simpler model (eg a single cube stacked on top of another cube). Then start adding features to your model until it breaks.